# VBA Excel couldn't find custom values from MS Project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I've been trying to find Text1 from MS Project using Excel VBA .Find method but it doesn't seem to be working. I have a working code but it is very slow because it loops through every task. Here is my code:

```
Sub Exp()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "MPD", "*.mpp*"
       If .Show = True Then
          Dim getfilename As String
          Dim appProj As MSProject.Application
          Dim Found As Boolean
          Dim TaskObject As Object
          getfilename = .SelectedItems(1)
          Set appProj = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")
             appProj.FileOpen (getfilename)
             appProj.Visible = True
          Found = appProj.Find (Field:="Text1", Test:="equals", Value:="Exp1")
          If Found Then
             Set TaskObject = appProj.ActiveCell.Task
             Debug.Print TaskObject.UniqueID & " - " & TaskObject.Name
          Else
             MsgBox "Not Found"
          End If
       End If
    End With
   End Sub
```

How can i get this code working or is there another way of doing this?
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

[Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.find) is a method of the Application object, not the Project object. So the correct way to use it is this:

```
Found = Application.Find(Field:="UniqueID", Test:="equals", Value:="130")
```

However, there is a faster way to get a reference to a task object by way of its UniqueID by using the [UniqueID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.tasks.uniqueid) property of the Tasks object:

```
Set TaskObject = ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(130)
```

Comment: Hey, i think i explained myself wrong. I don't have the UniqueID and i am trying to find it by searching from custom Text1 values. I tried the Application object but still getting an error. I updated the questions main code and the question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: First try working in MS Project itself using the Find method to get that part working. Use the Immediate window using `Find` and for the value, copy the value from the task directly so that you're sure the value is correct (e.g. no trailing spaces, typos, etc).